# How can I make Entity Framework map a DbDataReader?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to make Entity Framework return multiple results for custom queries then have it map back to Entity Framework Code First models. Is it possible to use the internal mapping engine of Entity Framework?

I can guarantee that the rows returned by both queries in the result sets map directly to an EF model. As an internal requirement, I can't use a stored procedure.

```
public void MultipleResultSets()
{
    var db = new DbContext();
    var command = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.CommandText =
        @"
        SELECT * FROM TableA; 
        SELECT * FROM TableB;
        ";

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Map Table A rows
        var tableARows = new List<TableARow>();
        while (reader.Read())
            tableARows.Add(reader.Map<TablARow>()); // "Map()" is not real

        reader.NextResult();

        // Map Table B rows
        var tableBRows = new List<TableBRow>();
        while (reader.Read())
            tableARows.Add(reader.Map<TablBRow>()); // "Map()" is not real
    }
    command.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this to be a query that returns multiple resultsets instead of just sending two queries?

Comment: @Pawel, reduce the number of database round trips.

Comment: Not sure if it's worth it but you can expose each result set as DbDataReader and use the `ObjectContext.Translate` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [EF+](http://entityframework-plus.net/).

Here is an extension method you can find from my repository which uses the internal mapping engine for mapping a data reader.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MapReader<T>(this DbContext context, DbDataReader reader) where T : class
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(reader);    
}
```

You can then use your code like this:

```
public void MultipleResultSets()
{
    var db = new DbContext();
    var command = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.CommandText =
        @"
        SELECT * FROM TableA; 
        SELECT * FROM TableB;
        ";

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Map Table A rows
        var tableARows = db.MapReader<TableA>(reader);

        reader.NextResult();

        // Map Table B rows
        var tableBRows = db.MapReader<TableB>(reader);
    }
    command.Connection.Close();
}
```

**Note**: The extension method has been updated to use Pawel answer "ObjectContext.Translate"

Comment: This looks great. I tried running it against one of my tables and received the following error about a nullable decimal column (note, I'm using MySQL). See stack trace at http://pastebin.com/HRvqtRbR

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The 'ColumnA' property on 'TableA' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Decimal'.

Comment: I tested it with MySQL and it worked great. This method have the same limitations as SqlQuery<TEntity> so try using it for every query to check if the issue is with one of your query: "db.Database.SqlQuery<Student>("SELECT * FROM TableA").ToList();"

Comment: Using the `Translate` method worked with the query that didn't work before.